# v-data-table not showing all the rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify v-data-table component. The issue I am facing here is that last row doesn't display. Right now the output I am getting is

```
James
Jack
William
Ross
```

But the actual output show be

```
James
Jack
William
Ross
Jimmy
```

If I remove the unshift code from the fetchUser method then I get

```
Jack
William
Ross
Jimmy
```

So basically it shows only 4 items but in actual it should be 5 items. If I check the users array in the console it shows all the 5 records but in v-data-table it shows just 4 rows. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
 <template>
    <div class="table-layout">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :hide-default-footer="true"
        class="user-table"
      >
        <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
          <tr>
            <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: ' ',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          }
        ],
        users: []
      };
    },
    created: function() {
      this.fetchUsers();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchUsers(){
        var url = '/users.json';
        this.$axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          this.users = response.data
          this.users.unshift({
            name: 'James'
          });
        })
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
    <div class="table-layout">
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :hide-default-footer="true"
        class="user-table"
        disable-pagination
      >
        <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
          <tr>
            <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>
```

adding disable-pagination to v-data-table solved my issue.